# Remove Cookie from Web API 2 Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to do an authenticated web api request that does not reset the authentication cookie timeout. In the MVC world I would accomplish this by removing the FormsAuthenication cookie from the responce:

```
 Response.Cookies.Remove(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
```

In Web API 2 I wrote a custom IHttpActionResult, and I am removing the Set-Cookie header from the response. This is however, not removing the header, as I still see the Set-Cookie header when the auth cookie is being updated for the requests that use this action result.

Here is the custom IHttpActionResult:

```
public class NonAuthResetResult<T> : IHttpActionResult where T: class
{
    private HttpRequestMessage _request;
    private T _body;

    public NonAuthResetResult(HttpRequestMessage request, T body)
    {
        _request = request;
        _body = body;
    }

    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; private set; }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var msg = _request.CreateResponse(_body);
        msg.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");
        return Task.FromResult(msg);
    }
}
```

How do I edit the response header in Web API 2, because this is not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Global.asax can remove cookies in the Application_EndRequest event.  And you can set a variable to be later picked up by Application_EndRequest.

Step 1. Create an action filter which sets a variable in Context.Items:

```
public class NoResponseCookieAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("remove-auth-cookie", "true");
    }
}
```

Step 2. Handle the Application_EndRequest event in your global.asax file.  If the variable from Step 1 is present, remove the cookie.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Items["remove-auth-cookie"] != null)
    {
        Context.Response.Cookies.Remove(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    }
}
```

Step 3. Decorate your web api actions with the custom filter:

```
[NoResponseCookie]
public IHttpActionResult GetTypes()
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Web API 2, you're probably using the OWIN Cookie Middleware. What you are describing sounds like you want to disable the sliding expiry window on the auth cookie.

In the standard Web API template, you should have an App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs. In it you'll find the line...

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
```

This enables and configures the cookie middleware. You can pass in some options to change the timeout window and disable sliding expiry...

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    SlidingExpiration = false,
    ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0) // 1 hour
});
```

Comment: I need to do this for a specific request. Not a global Web API setting.